# User Authentication API

Tags: encryption, web-application, passwords, authentication, web-service

I'm developing a web API for a user database that will be used to verify a given username / password combination is valid.

I'm just looking for comments / criticism on the following method that I'm planning to use:

- API Key records are stored within the database
- Each API Key record consists of a public API key and a private API key
- API clients use the private API key to salt the hashing of the given username / password
- Username, password, and public API key are sent via HTTP GET request to the API for validation
- A custom response code is returned based on what happens at the server

Is this a secure way of proceeding?  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should always use HTTPS not HTTP.  Disallow HTTP use altogether

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on your third point?

Answer (score 1):

1. Always use HTTP POST for sending data to the server.GET should be used for fetching the data.
2. You should always use HTTPS for your web service.

> API clients use the private API key to salt the hashing of the given username / password

If you are referring to the private key of your authentication server then this is a wrong approach.The private key of the server should not be kept with the client.If you are using a secure connection then you need not perform password hashing on the client side and let your server handle the load.

[here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) is a good reference for password hashing techniques and using the salt.